# Sorting Arrays/File I/O C++

Tags: c++, arrays, io

I was wondering is someone could help me out of sorting this array, I am i little lost on how to exactly implement it in this project. Because it is HW do not reveal the whole answer, but push me towards the right direction. The project is as follows: 
Write a program that will read a line of text and output a list of all the letters that occur in the text together with the number of times each letter occurs in the line. End the line with a period that serves as a sentinel value. The letters should be used in the following order: highest to lowest.Assume that the input used all lowercase letters. 
A couple questions. 
1. Am I going along the right way in sorting the array?
2. Before putting the sorting array into my code, when the code compiles it comes up with a blank screen. Any ways to fix this?

Apologies if this is written poorly, and thanks in advance for the help!

```
inlcude <iostream>
#inlcude <fstream>
using namespace std;
void initialize(int list[]);
void Sort(int list[],int& num);
void characterCount(char ch, int list[]);
void readText(ifstream& intext, char& ch, int list[]);
void totalCount(int list[]);
int main()
{
int index,letterCount[26];
char ch;
ifstream inFile;

infile.open("C:/temp/Data_Chapter_7_8.txt");

if (!inFile)
{
   cout << " Cannot open file." <<endl;
}
initialize(letterCount);
infile.get(ch);

while (inFile)
{
  int index;
  readText(inFile,ch,letterCount)
  index++;
  inFile.get(ch);
  }
  totalCount(index, letterCount);

  inFile.close();

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
  }
  //initializes array letterCount to 0
  void initialize(int list[])
  {
 for(int x = 0;x<26;x++)
 list[x] = 0
 }
 //increments the letter count. Makes sure counting letters.
 void characterCount (char ch, int list[])
 {
 int index;
 ch = tolower(ch);
 if(static_cast<int>(ch)>=97&&(static_cast<int>(ch)<=122))
  letterCount[static_cast<int>(ch)-97]++;  
  }
  void readText(ifstream& intext, char& ch, int list[])
  { 
  while (ch != '.')
  {
  characterCount (ch,list);
  intext.get(ch);
  }
  }
  //displays data
  void totalCount(int list[])
  {
 for(int x=0;x<26;x++)
 if(letterCount[x]>0)  
 cout<<static_cast<char>(x+97)<<" "<<letterCount[x]<<endl;
 }
 void Sort(int list[],int& num)
      {
 int i,j,flag = 1;
 int temp;
 int numLength = num.length();
 for (i=1;(i<=numLength)&&flag; i++)
 {
     flag = 0;
     for (j=o; j<(numLength-1);j++0
     {
         if(num[j+1]>num[j])
         {
             temp = num[j];
             num[j] = num[j+1];
             num[j+1]=temp;
             flag = 1;
         }
     }
 }
             return;
             }
```

Comment: People not giving full, good quality answers is part of the reason the homework tag is now deprecated. Just throwing it out there.

Comment: give us an example of your file so we have something to go off of.

Comment: The file is Just is Oliver was a Golden Retreiver whose fur was long and golden.

Comment: (a) `inFile` is undefined. (b) in function `characterCount()` the variable `letterCount` is undefined, (c) in `Sort()` function `o` is undefined (initializer of for loop), (d) the invoke of `totalCount()` in `main() does not match its prototype. Summary: how do you know it doesn't work when it *doesn't even **compile*** ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using messy bubble sorts and other fun stuff, we can simply keep track of the number of occurrences of each letter, since there are only 26 possibilities. This should result in a bit cleaner (and much faster) code:

```
int numOccur[26];
...
for (int i = 0; i < numCh; i ++)
    numOccur[letters[i] - 'a'] ++;
for (i = 25; i >= 0; i --)
    if (i > 0)
        cout<<static_cast<char>(i+97)<<" "<<numOccur[i]<<endl;
```

Of course, you should replace the for loop with the appropriate file-reading loop.

Comment: Any system where `'a' - 'a' != 0` or `'z' - 'a' >= 26`?

Comment: @jma127: Yes -- on an IBM mainframe (using EBCDIC) `'z'-'a'` will be greater than 26 (if memory serves, it's around 32, but don't quote me on that).

Comment: @jma127 IBM AS/400, IBM OS/390 to name a few (see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) and work the math.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; never knew that before. Seems a bit obscure, though.

Comment: @jma127 read the article. it does a decent job of explaining the origins. And I can personally attest to the PITA that is can sometimes be to work on.

Comment: @user1705380 Your loop should have as a condition that EOF has not been reached: `while (!inFile.eof())`. Inside, you need to increment the appropriate array element for each character. Replace `letters[i]` in my loop with your character reading function.

Comment: @jma127: No -- `while (!infile.eof())` is essentially always a bug (just as bad as the `while (infile)` he has now). See my answer for the correct form.

Comment: Would `infile.good()` be the same, or is it safer than `.eof()`?

Answer (score 0):

Just a few comments.

1. I don't see any good reason for most of the casting here.
2. Use `isalpha`, `isupper` or `islower` to check for letters, and `tolower` or `toupper` to covnert them (Note: using these functions is one of the few justifications for casting).
3. Probably easiest to initialize your `lettercount` array with `int lettercount[26] ={0};
4. Unless you're absolutely required to write your own sort routine, just use `std::sort`.
5. It's usually easiest to open a file as you define your ifstream: 
    `std::ifstream infile("whatever");`
6. Don't use `while (infile)`. It's pretty much a guaranteed bug. Do a read, and check whether it succeeded, like: `while (infile.get(ch)) ...`